# Match columns with at least one similar word

Tags: r, match, grepl

I have two data frames. I want to replace the IDs in DF1 for the IDs in DF2. 
I know I can do this:

```
 DF1$ID<-DF2$ID[match(DF1$NAME,DF2$NAME, incomparables = NA)]
```

But I want to add `grepl` or something similar, to recognize at least one word from `DF1$NAME` that coincides with `DF2$NAME`

So in the case of the example, I want to match the words "sodium" although in DF2 it says Sodium complete

So this is the example:

DF1

```
   NAME        ID    value
 sodium        NA     0,1
 chloride      NA     0,5
```

DF2

```
      NAME              ID    value
 sodium complete       123    0,5
 chloride complete     456    0,8
```

Result in DF1

```
             ID    value
 sodium      123    0,1
 chloride    456     0,5
```

How can I do this in a general way, since my data is bigger and with more names to match.

Thank you!

Comment: please share the output of `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)`

Comment: if the df is too big, use `dput(head(df))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with `grepl`,

```
sapply(df1$NAME, function(i)df2$ID[grepl(i, df2$NAME)])
#  sodium chloride 
#     123      456
```

Assign it to your `ID` column,

```
df1$ID <- sapply(df1$NAME, function(i) df2$ID[grepl(i, df2$NAME)])
df1
#      NAME  ID value
#1   sodium 123   0.1
#2 chloride 456   0.5
```

A slightly different syntax as per @snoram can be,

```
df2$ID[sapply(df1$NAME, function(x) grep(x, df2$NAME)[1])]
```

Comment: Was just about to post this: `df2$ID[sapply(df1$NAME, function(x) grep(x, df2$NAME)[1])]` which I think might improve performance a bit but hardly merits its own answer.

Comment: @snoram True. I 'll add it here just for variety

Answer (score 0):

Use [fuzzyjoin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/README.html)-

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
df1 <- data.frame(
  "NAME" = c("sodium", "chloride"),
  "value" = c("0,1","0,2")
)
df1$ID <- NA

df2 <- data.frame(
  "NAME" = c("sodium", "chloride"),
  "ID" = c(123,456),
  "value" = c("0,1","0,2")
)

# Here is the actual logic
df <- stringdist_inner_join(df1,df2, by="NAME")
df
df <- df[,c("NAME.x","ID.y", "value.x")]
colnames(df) <- c("NAME", "ID", "value")
rownames(df) <- df$NAME
df$NAME <- NULL
df
```

**Output**

```
          ID value
sodium   123   0,1
chloride 456   0,2
```